# Git: Commit folders and files

Tags: git, commit

Mistakenly, I have committed the files in wrong repository and now want to commit same bunch of files in right repository.

so I have made some changes in those files so that those files would come up in change list. But those are not visible in the change list.

Can anyone let me know how to do it? Or I am doing anything wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is the output of `git status`? Did you `git add` the changes? We need more information to help you.

Comment: Steps I did it in wrong repository:
git status, git add ., git push origin branch_name, git status

Comment: The directory where your files are located would belong to only one repository, you can't commit them to the wrong repository, so something else is going on. Is this a brand new local repository that you have on your machine, and you have somehow connected that to the wrong upstream repository ?

Comment: This is too little information to help you ... maybe `git reflog` may help you.

Comment: @Trupti Could it be that you in fact meant you commited on the wrong *branch* instead of wrong *repository* ? Ignore my question if you know it's not the case, I just wanted to exclude this possible misunderstanding on the terms.

Comment: No, I have committed in wrong repository...

Answer (score 0):

If your files are completely independent of other files in your wrong repository, you can try the following:

Add the wrong repository as new `wrong` remote:

```
git remote add wrong <path-to-wrong-repository>
```

Fetch the `wrong` remote content:

```
git fetch wrong
```

Localize the commits you want (you should have now 2 independent history trees):

```
git log --graph --all --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
```

Cherry-pick the list of commits you want:

```
git cherry-pick <sha1-first>~1..<sha1-last>
```

Remove the `wrong` remote:

```
git remote remove wrong
```